# Grinding noise when braking _and_ turning left

Tags: ford, brakes, noise, escape

My 2008 Ford Escape started doing this on the way home today - scared me to death! I was coming downhill on a left-turning road and I felt like I had blown a tire and was riding on the rim - some loss of control, a grinding sound. As I went (slowly) home, I figured out that it only happens when braking *and* turning left. Google was unhelpful - just got a lot of results about grinding noises when turning in general.

Comment: I would have the wheel bearings checked on the front.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Wouldn't bearing make noise more often?

Comment: Check the state of the front brake calipers and pads

Comment: This sounds like a CV axle problem, a bearing noise would be constant and vary with speed.

Comment: Took it to the shop today - we'll find out soon. I'll update when problem is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's the scoop:

It was the left front tone ring, which was causing the ABS to misfire.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy! There'd have to be something causing the reluctor ring to get out of alignment (at least I'm assuming that's what happened). Hopefully you figured out what was causing this to happen.

Comment: Can't speak to that - just found out about the existence of a tone ring :) Got it back from the shop today, and all seems well so far. Side note: guy said that the Escape is fairly unique in that the tone ring can be replaced without the whole assembly being changed out, so it wasn't horrendous